# Fixing a While loop in a pig latin translator

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm working on a pig latin translator program that:

1. Prompts the user for a word.
2. If the word begins with a vowel, append “way” to the end of the word.
3. If the word begins with a consonant, remove all consonants from the beginning of the word and append them to the end of the word. Then, append “ay” to the end of the word.
4. Halts when the user enters “quit” (any combination of lower and upper case letters, such as “QUIT”, “Quit” or “qUIt”)

My program satisfies 1-3 just fine but I cannot seem to figure out how to continuously prompt the user for a word unless they enter some form of "quit". I know I need to use a while statement, but this is the best I come up with:

```
while True:

VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")

statement = input("Please enter a word: ")
statementL = statement.lower()

if statementL == "quit":
    print ("Exiting program")
    break


def find_vowel(word):
   for i in range(len(word)):
     if word[i] in VOWELS:
        return i
   return -1

words =  statement.split()
count = 0

for word in words:
   vowel = find_vowel(word)
# No vowels found
   if(vowel == -1):
      print (word)
# A vowel is the first letter
   elif(vowel == 0):
    print (word + "way")
   else:
# A consonant is first
    print (word[vowel:] + word[:vowel] + "ay")
```

My current while loop constantly prompts the user to enter a word but doesn't translate it and I get an error when I try to move the quitting the program chunk to the bottom. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your indenting is off

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the issue is. I copied your code character for character and it ran correctly. The only issue that might exist is that your code that you believe to be in the while loop might not be. Check your indentation. Here is the code I ran:

```
while True:

    VOWELS = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U")

    statement = input("Please enter a word: ")
    statementL = statement.lower()

    if statementL == "quit":
        print ("Exiting program")
        break


    def find_vowel(word):
       for i in range(len(word)):
         if word[i] in VOWELS:
            return i
       return -1

    words =  statement.split()
    count = 0

    for word in words:
       vowel = find_vowel(word)
       # No vowels found
       if(vowel == -1):
          print (word)
       # A vowel is the first letter
       elif(vowel == 0):
          print (word + "way")
       else:
          # A consonant is first
          print (word[vowel:] + word[:vowel] + "ay")
```

Comment: Yeah, it was the indentation. I feel like an idiot haha. Thank you